# Devise session not persisting after login redirect on React-Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, devise, react-rails

We have a pretty standard React-Rails app with (prerender = true) (following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/technically-speaking/rails-react-browserify-e315001d5974#.7yesna64h) and his [accompanying repo](https://github.com/olance/rails-react-browserify-example)). We're currently using the Devise gem to implement users. However, right now after a successful login and the user is redirected to the home page (as is the default with Devise - we made no changes there) the user session is not persisted, meaning the user is logged out by the time the homepage is reached, according to the user_signed_in? function provided by devise.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey there, i'm facing a similar issue. Any chance that you solved it or got a workaround this? Would really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head and I'm having trouble finding the commit where we fixed it.  If I remember correctly, however, we had renamed our rails app and missed a couple places with the rename and that ended up causing this error.  Hope that helps!